# Postgres Row Level Security with UUIDs

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that has a UUID as the primary key. I'm wanting to set a RLS policy that will return a row if an existing UUID is specified such that:

```
SELECT * FROM table; -- Would fail the RLS policy since no existing UUID was specified
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 'bad-uuid'; -- Would also fail since the uuid doesn't exist
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 'existing-uuid'; -- Would return the single result
```

The goal is, if the user has been given a UUID, they can retrieve the data for that UUID and that UUID only. That said, I'm not sure how to pass on the 'existing-uuid' value to the RLS policy.

Comment: A function that returns the row would make more sense than a RLS policy here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use [RLS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html) to force a user to use a certain filter in their query. What it effectively does is it ***adds*** a session-dependent filter to each query based on your policy.

You could achieve this effect by moving that uuid to a [custom variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) and reference it from your policy or a session-dependent view. That way

- a `select * from table` by that user will fail if they didn't first run a `set my.uuid='some-uuid'`,
- `select * from table` will be equivalent to `select * from table where id = current_setting('my.uuid')` and it will return empty if they set a `'bad-uuid'`
- `select * from table where id = 'existing-uuid'` will still fail if they didn't run `set my.uuid='existing-uuid'` first

Session-dependent [view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/6G13gOgi)

```sql
create table my_table(id uuid, misc text);
insert into my_table values 
('cab0d6c6-5357-4afa-b48a-e60cb130d8c2','A'),
('cab0d6c6-5357-4afa-b48a-e60cb130d8c2','B'),
('4e663f99-9d31-47dc-931a-888be606fc00','C');

create view my_view as 
select * from my_table 
where id = current_setting('my.id')::uuid;

set my.id='cab0d6c6-5357-4afa-b48a-e60cb130d8c2';

select * from my_view; --row C not shown
--                  id                  | misc
----------------------------------------+------
-- cab0d6c6-5357-4afa-b48a-e60cb130d8c2 | A
-- cab0d6c6-5357-4afa-b48a-e60cb130d8c2 | B
```

Row-level security: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/I1ST2NL5) (note superusers bypass even forced RLS)

```sql
create table my_table(id uuid, misc text);
insert into my_table values 
('cab0d6c6-5357-4afa-b48a-e60cb130d8c2','A'),
('cab0d6c6-5357-4afa-b48a-e60cb130d8c2','B'),
('4e663f99-9d31-47dc-931a-888be606fc00','C');

alter table my_table enable row level security;
alter table my_table force row level security;--required to apply to owner

create policy show_one_known_uuid_only on my_table to current_user
  using (id = current_setting('my.id')::uuid);

set my.id='cab0d6c6-5357-4afa-b48a-e60cb130d8c2';

select * from my_table; --row C not shown
--                  id                  | misc
----------------------------------------+------
-- cab0d6c6-5357-4afa-b48a-e60cb130d8c2 | A
-- cab0d6c6-5357-4afa-b48a-e60cb130d8c2 | B
```

You could also hide the table behind a set- or table-returning function that only wraps a `select * from table where id=$1`, revoke permissions on the `table` from the user but let them use the function to read from it instead, forcing them to use the condition: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/rjvWZPMr)

```sql
create function my_func(my_id uuid) 
returns table (like my_table) language sql security definer as $func$
select * from my_table where id=$1; $func$;

select * from my_func(gen_random_uuid()/*aka "bad-uuid"*/ );
-- id | misc
------+------
--(0 rows)

select * from my_func('cab0d6c6-5357-4afa-b48a-e60cb130d8c2');
--                  id                  | misc
----------------------------------------+------
-- cab0d6c6-5357-4afa-b48a-e60cb130d8c2 | A
-- cab0d6c6-5357-4afa-b48a-e60cb130d8c2 | B
--(2 rows)
```